# Is there a way to know the number of records added into the SQL database after a particular date and time

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle11g

The table doesn't have any date time column. I want to if there is any inbuilt keyword which can does that.
I want to know all commits done after a particular date.

Comment: All the more reason why your table should have a timestamp column if you have this requirement.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen actually this table created long back and it doesn't have any kind of the above mentioned requirement. But this table is general table utilized by many of my teammates. To track the changes made to this table, i want to know if there is a possibility as such.

Answer (score 1):

If flashback is enabled on the database you can get records on the table in an around a particular date range in Oracle.(It purely depends on if its enabled and for how long the flashback needs to be kept)
You can query to see the data in the table as of 3 days back as follows

```
select *
  from table as of timestamp sysdate-3
```